# SQL Query to calculate time correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below SQL Query that calculates various fields as well as the total amount of time. The outcome of the time from this query is a decimal number instead of total hours and minutes HH:MM

The table in SQL has the time in HH:MM:SS format in it.

Is there any way I can tweak the below SQL query so the output of the time calculation will be in HH:MM ?

Thank you in advance,

Thanasis

```
                public static function PilotAircraftFlownCounts($pilotid)
{
    $key = 'ac_flown_counts_'.$pilotid;

    $counts = CodonCache::read($key);

    if($counts === false)
    {
        //Select aircraft types
        $sql =  'SELECT a.name AS aircraft, COUNT(p.aircraft) AS count, SUM(p.flighttime) AS hours
                FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'pireps p, '.TABLE_PREFIX.'aircraft a 
                WHERE p.aircraft = a.id AND p.pilotid='.intval($pilotid).'
                GROUP BY a.name';

        $counts = DB::get_results($sql);
        CodonCache::write($key, $counts, 'medium');
    }

    return $counts;
}
```

Comment: Show the table definition.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL (I'm not sure if this is in other databases or not), you can use the SEC_TO_TIME function to reformat your seconds in HH:MM:SS format. Perhaps:

```
$sql =  'SELECT a.name AS aircraft, COUNT(p.aircraft) AS count, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(p.flighttime)) AS hours FROM ' .
        TABLE_PREFIX . 'pireps p, TABLE_PREFIX' .
        'aircraft a WHERE p.aircraft = a.id AND p.pilotid=' . 
        intval($pilotid) . 'GROUP BY a.name';
```

Comment: That could work if flighttime is stored in a time-based column.

Comment: flighttime is indeed a time-based column. Copied your code and the results I get are: Aircraft A: 16 , Aircraft B: 0 . The correct time in HH:MM format if I manually add it from the DB columns are: Aircraft A: 07:12 , Aircraft B: 00:25 ...

Comment: @Grumman, your sum is in hours, not seconds. Multiply the sum by 3600 to convert to seconds. SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(p.flighttime) *3600))

Answer (score 0):

I think that's an "almost."  **If the flighttime is measured in hours** (as a decimal or other numeric type), you really want this:

CONCAT(FLOOR(SUM(p.flighttime)), ":", ROUND((SUM(p.flighttime)-FLOOR(SUM(p.flighttime)))*60)) AS hours

Comment: We are going somewhere with this but we are not quite there yet. :) Before the result was Aircraft A: 5.92 Aircraft B: 2.5. With this one now I get Aircraft A: 59.200 and Aircraft B: 2.500 ...